# ld: warning: could not create compact unwind for _ffi_call_unix64: does not use RBP or RSP based frame Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, python-2.7, pyobject

I am trying to include Python.framework into iOS from [here](https://github.com/pybee/Python-iOS-support).

I got the following errors:

> ld: warning: could not create compact unwind for _ffi_call_unix64:
>   does not use RBP or RSP based frame Undefined symbols for architecture
>   x86_64:
>       "_adler32", referenced from:
>         _zlib_adler32 in Python(zlibmodule.o) "_sqlite3_user_data", referenced from:
>         __pysqlite_func_callback in Python(connection.o)
>         __pysqlite_step_callback in Python(connection.o)   "_sqlite3_value_blob", referenced from:
>         __pysqlite_build_py_params in Python(connection.o)   "_sqlite3_value_bytes", referenced from:
>         __pysqlite_build_py_params in Python(connection.o)   "_sqlite3_value_double", referenced from:
>         __pysqlite_build_py_params in Python(connection.o)   "_sqlite3_value_int64", referenced from:
>         __pysqlite_build_py_params in Python(connection.o)   "_sqlite3_value_text", referenced from:
>         __pysqlite_build_py_params in Python(connection.o)   "_sqlite3_value_type", referenced from:
>         __pysqlite_build_py_params in Python(connection.o)   "_zlibVersion", referenced from:
>         _PyInit_zlib in Python(zlibmodule.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)